# HttpServletResponse PrintWriter to write an InputStream

Tags: servlets, inputstream, printwriter

I have a HttpServletResponse object and need to write a file contained in the jar. The following code segments do not work for me.

```
URI uri = <myclass>.class.getResource("/" + filename).toURI(); 
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
File f = new File(uri); 
FileReader bis = new FileReader(f);
char[] buff = new char[1024];
int bytesRead;
// Simple read/write loop.
while (-1 != (bytesRead = bis.read(buff, 0, buff.length))) {
    out.write(buff, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

I know that this will work

```
InputStream inputStream = <myclass>.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + filename);
```

but I cannot get the PrintWriter out.write to write the inputStream.

Can anyone tell me how this can be done.

Thanks

Comment: sorry, need to read a file that is within the jar, a resource file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resolved using the following

```
InputStream inputStream = KCSSchemaController.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + schemaname);

OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();

ByteStreams.copy(inputStream, output);

output.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

> *need to write a file contained in the jar.*

That's not possible this way. You'd basically need to get an absolute disk file system path to the JAR file, extract it using [`JarInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarInputStream.html) (a JAR is basically a ZIP file which follows a specific folder structure and get special treatment by Java), edit/add the file in the extracted folder structure and then package it again using [`JarOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarOutputStream.html). You'll possibly need to reload it afterwards using a (custom) [`ClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) if you need the changed JAR contents later during runtime.

This is however pretty complicated and makes no sense. As a completely different alternative, do not attempt to change the JAR, but just store the data somewhere else, e.g. on a fixed location on disk file system, or in a database, or as an user/system preference, etcetera. Which way to choose depends on the concrete functional requirement which is not clear from the question.

Comment: sorry, need to read a file that is within the jar, a resource file.

Comment: If you only need to *read* it (not to write it!), just use `ClassLoader#getResourseAsStream()` the usual way.